# No Images are Displaying on IE11, but Display on FF, Chrome, and Edge

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I am currently working on a project, built using flex, that currently for whatever reason doesn't display any of the images, minus the logo, on Internet Explorer 11. The images display correctly on Edge, Chrome, and FF. From what I could find there is an ::after and ::before properties on the image tags with a max-width:100%, as soon as I remove the max width property the images appear, but the site alters slightly. Is there any solution to fix the image issue without removing the max-width property from the ::before and ::after?

Comment: Do you mean `flexbox`? This feature is only partial supported on IE 11. You can check here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: @Danibix Ah yes, sorry for that. I'm using flexbox.

Comment: For us to be able to give a proper answer, post a minimal part of your code reproducing the issue

Comment: Yea, I'm currently working on reproducing it. I think I figured it out sort of, I will definitely post my progress!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a hidden max-width in the min.css file, I changed that to width instead. This however caused some further editing on the website, but after all the editing everything worked correctly.